# Do we need a "list-filtering" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

It seems to me that a comparatively high percentage of questions have to do with filtering a list, such as removing duplicates or selecting elements of various descriptions.  Many of these are probably pseudo-duplicates or at least very closely related.  I would like to start tagging these questions to make it easy to find them.
The existing [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) tag is too broad to search for these effectively.

I want to be sure that whatever tag is chosen does not conflict with other meanings of the term filter or filtering such as [signal processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29) or [pure mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29).

Do you believe we need such a tag, and is [list-filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-filtering) a good choice?

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I could judge it better if your post showed a tag wiki for the proposed tag.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't know if I have anything more specific than "... such as removing duplicates or selecting elements of various descriptions ..." -- What about a list of questions I think should have the tag?

Comment: I think it important that, if we add a new tag for the purpose of fine tuning a tag like [tag:list-manipulation] which already exists, that the new tag have a tag wiki making the discrimination between the new tag and the old very clear.

Comment: @m_goldberg Okay, I see your point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) alone is too broad, but [list-filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-filtering) will eventually suffer from the same problem as well. I think the problem here is that while list-manipulation is a perfectly good umbrella tag for such questions, most users don't use additional tags to narrow down the scope (or if they do, they use/create highly specific tags).

A solution would be to use secondary tags such as [sorting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting), [gathering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gathering), [duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates), [filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering), etc. in addition to list-manipulation. I like this solution because

- it automatically categorizes these questions using common and well known search terms, rather than a new tag which someone might not know about. Searching for these questions is easy, since the results returned are the intersection of the sets (tags).
- it can be used for other combinations, such as [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation)+[sorting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) or [signal-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing)+[filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering), etc. without having to create localized tags such as [string-filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-filtering) or [signal-filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-filtering), etc.

I think this is one of the strong points of SE's tagging system, but in practice, it's not often done this way. Users might use only one or the other and it's up to the editors of the site to retag appropriately (e.g. a question with just [filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) should not be left as is).

Comment: I find this idea great. Also, I see no objections from others so I added one tag today to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31199/5478). Should I edit tag-wiki?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, please.

Comment: Ok, done, I will appreciate the review. I was thinking about adding refferece to releated functions like `DeleteDuplicates` e.g. but I decided it is not good idea because filtering question do not have to involve those functions and questions about those functions do not have to be about filtering.

Comment: @Kuba I reviewed the suggested edits and it seems like you misread my answer :) I was suggesting that the [tag:filtering] tag could be used for multiple purposes, with the main tag (list-manipulation/string-manipulation/signal-processing) indicating the exact usage. Although both were opposite to what was written here, I approved (improved) one and rejected (improved) the other, depending on how much I had to rewrite :)

Comment: I see it's done. I'm sorry I don;t know what I was thinking about :) I do agree with your idea.

Comment: I don't agree with the idea of using a single tag for multiple different concepts. What is meant by "list filtering" is not at all the same as a filter in the DSP sense. I would rather have tags to represent specific concepts rather than just keywords that can just as well appear in the body of the post itself. [tag:list-manipulation] arguably does encompass a too-wide range of *operations*, but conceptually it is quite well defined, IMO.