# What additional tag should questions like this have? (measurements from image)

Tags: discussion, tagging

I believe [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32830/121) needs a tag besides [image-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) to specify its  measurement and analysis aspect.

Please provide answers with either reasons *not* to have such a tag or with one tag recommendation.

Comment: Can you justify the need for a new tag? Are there several other questions that could potentially benefit from this tag?

Comment: @rm-rf Okay, that's fair.  I believe I have seen several other questions for which such a tag would be appropriate but I didn't take the time to find them.  As you may have noticed I've been spending less time on the site this last week.  I'll look later.

Comment: This might be silly, but what's wrong with [tag:computational-geometry]?

Comment: @István That has a different connotation to me, but that might be personal.  Propose it in an answer if you care to.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion such tag for only a purpose of image related measurements would be an overreaction. But, since we approved an existance of [secondary tags](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1087/5478) I think

- [data-analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-analysis)

working with [image-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) is quite good idea. Also, it could be used with [data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data), [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data), [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) to improve the scope of questions like [How to find all local maxima](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5575/5478).

A good wiki description is required to avoid overdosing it *with/instead of* [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

One tag that would fit is [mensuration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mensuration). My thought was to just add it and write a brief-form tag wiki for it (see below). But, deferring to Mr.Wizard's question, I offer it here first for approval.

> Questions related to the measurement of geometric magnitudes of 2D and 3D objects represented as *Mathematica* objects or depicted as areas or voxel-regions in an image.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use [computational-geometry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry).

It has a very short, uninformative wiki at the moment, but in my understanding, this covers measurements and similar as well. From Wikipedia:

> "Computational geometry is a branch of computer science devoted to the study of algorithms which can be stated in terms of geometry." [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry)

Furthermore, geometry (especially Euclidean, and that is what we use here most of the time) has strong links to:

> "computational geometry, computer graphics, convex geometry, discrete geometry, and some areas of combinatorics." [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry#Euclidean_geometry)

Also, geometry of a space involves calculations of topology and metrics defined over the space, which (I would say) is exactly what the example question is about (identify, count and measure geometrical properties of particles).

As an independent act, the tag wiki should certainly be improved.