# GeoGraphics vs. Geography

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tags [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) and [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) are often used together, but inconsistently so, yet with overlapping concerns, e.g. a "`GeoGraphics`" question

[PlotMarkers in GeoListPlot do not work](http://%20https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123952/52)

vs. a "`Geography`" question

[upper limit with `PlotStyle` in `GeoListPlot` in v10.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80369/52)

The boundary between the two is often fuzzy, but I believe a clear boundary can be created by strictly having only geographic plotting in [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) and anything else geography related (entities, `GeoDistance`, etc.) go in [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography). Obviously, there is still quite a bit of overlap, but I think this is a reasonable distinction and the tag descriptions should be updated. Agreed? However, this brings up other questions.

1. Is [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) distinct enough from [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) to warrant a separate tag? (I believe so, but I prefer consensus.)
2. Where do the geoplots (`GeoListPlot`, `GeoHistogram`, etc.) go: [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting),[geoplotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoplotting), or [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics)?

Comment: I'd go with [tag:graphics]+[tag:geography] for `GeoGraphics`, + [tag:plotting] for the rest and other appropriate combinations for other cases, like [tag:curated-data] or [tag:filtering]

Comment: Another one why we should not use [tag:geographics] tag, it can be easily put in the query as it is very specific term.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition of geography. With the definition I grew up with, most of the [tag:geography] questions seem to have little to do with geography beyond political boundaries (= "geographics"?). I'd recommend making them synonyms.

Comment: @Kuba [tag:graphics3d] is a counter-case to that.

Comment: To my second point?

Comment: @Kuba yes. `Graphics3D` was considered separate enough to warrant its own tag, and in general, I believe `GeoGraphics` warrants the same. But, I'm not against merging it with [tag:graphics], nor am I particularly for it.

Comment: @rcollyer I see, well I must say I'm not entirely happy about graphics3d/graphics/plotting wikis.

Comment: @Kuba I agree with that. I think [tag:geography] needs to stand on its own for functions like `GeoDistance`, `GeoArea`, etc. as merging them with [tag:curated-data] is not a great fit. Thinking about it, adding [tag:geographics] as a synonym for [tag:graphics] is not unreasonable, and shunting the geoplotting functions into [tag:plotting] works well enough for me.

Comment: Thus far the voting has really cleared things up ... o_O

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative Partial Merge Option**:

I understand arguments for having [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) but I think that considering a big picutre we should use [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) as a secondary tag similarly to how [filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) was agreed to be used: [Do we need a "list-filtering" tag?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1085/5478)

Here is mu proposition:

- make [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) a synonym for [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) or [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) (not sure 100% but probably to former one is better)
- for questions about `GeoGraphics` use [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics)+[geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)
- for questions about `GeoListPlot, GeoHistogram`: [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting)+[geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)
- other geography related topics: [appropriate-tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appropriate-tag) + [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)
- adjust wikis analogously to [filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) wiki

Answer (score 2):

**Completely separate option**:

- Leave [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) separate as while the creation of a `GeoGraphics` object, by hand, is very similar to `Graphics` the underlying processing is very different. This follows the current path that [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [graphics3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics3d) are supposed to follow.
- [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) is then reserved for functions like `GeoDistance`, etc.
- Functions like `GeoListPlot`, `GeoRegionValuePlot`, etc. which output a `GeoGraphics` object are put into [geoplotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoplotting) in an analogous manner to [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) as they *usually* don't require direct manipulation of primitives and directives.

Comment: For upvoters, we don't have [tag:graphs-and-networks-plotting], do we want to go this way?

Answer (score 0):

**Full merge option**:

- Make [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) a synonym to [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) turning the latter into a category for "the direct use of primitives and directives in creating a 2D graphic."
- [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) is then reserved for functions like `GeoDistance`, etc.
- Functions like `GeoListPlot`, `GeoRegionValuePlot`, etc. which output a `GeoGraphics` object are put into [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) as they *usually* don't require direct manipulation of primitives and directives.

Answer (score -2):

**Partial merge option**:

- Leave [geographics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geographics) separate as while the creation of a `GeoGraphics` object, by hand, is very similar to `Graphics` the underlying processing is very different. This follows the current path that [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [graphics3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics3d) are supposed to follow.
- [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) is then reserved for functions like `GeoDistance`, etc.
- Functions like `GeoListPlot`, `GeoRegionValuePlot`, etc. which output a `GeoGraphics` object are put into [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) as they *usually* don't require direct manipulation of primitives and directives.